# WPF event on re-draw

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, rendering

I have some code which renders the contents of a Canvas to a bitmap. Periodically, child elements of the Canvas can change visually and I need a way of discerning when this has happened so that I can re-draw the Bitmap. My initial idea was to override `Canvas.OnRender` but this doesn't seem to get called when a child re-renders.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that WPF is not redrawn on a frame base, but more on the concept of dirty regions. Also OnRender is not like OnPaint, its used to create a cached representation to render the actual content, in most cases its not necessary to re-render to display some changes, thats why its not called. To get the effect you want, you could use the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event. Its propably the closest you can get to a paint event. 
But one warning, the moment you attach to that event, the rendering behavior changes a bit check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613584.aspx#CompositionTarget_Rendering_Event).

Another idea might be to look into [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx).

Comment: The problem with this is that it fires constantly, rather than when a dirty region is detected. An event that indicates that a region has been marked dirty would be ideal. I notice in the WPF Performance Suite that dirty regions can be highlighted so this data must be available somewhere...

Comment: propably using a VisualBrush and the Changed event. Snoop does something similar.